# AWS Elasticsearch restore index from backup stuck with "primary shard for this replica is not yet active"

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

When performing a restore of a specific index (using `POST /_snapshot/s3-bucket/snapshot-name/_restore`) on a new AWS Managed ElasticSearch cluster (version 7.1) it is getting stuck in Red state due to `primary shard for this replica is not yet active`.

*What does this error mean?*

`GET /_cluster/allocation/explain` returns:

```json
{
    "index": "myindex",
    "shard": 3,
    "primary": false,
    "current_state": "unassigned",
    "unassigned_info": {
        "reason": "NEW_INDEX_RESTORED",
        "at": "2021-06-14T19:24:34.589Z",
        "details": "restore_source[my-s3-bucket/my-snapshot]",
        "last_allocation_status": "no_attempt"
    },
    "can_allocate": "no",
    "allocate_explanation": "cannot allocate because allocation is not permitted to any of the nodes",
    "node_allocation_decisions": [
        {
            "node_id": "node-id",
            "node_name": "node-name",
            "node_decision": "no",
            "deciders": [
                {
                    "decider": "replica_after_primary_active",
                    "decision": "NO",
                    "explanation": "primary shard for this replica is not yet active"
                },
                {
                    "decider": "throttling",
                    "decision": "NO",
                    "explanation": "primary shard for this replica is not yet active"
                }
            ]
        },
        // Identical errors for the other 2 nodes.
    ]
}
```

*Does `last_allocation_status: no_attempt` mean I need to trigger the allocation somehow? If so, how can this be done on AWS where the `/_cluster/reroute` endpoint is not allowed?*

Other indices from the same snapshot restored OK. `/_cat/recovery?v&active_only=true` is empty. There is >100Gb of free space and low CPU usage on each node. The index is 3.8 million documents (store.size 5.4gb). Deleting and re-restoring the index consistently produces the same issue.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you check why primary shard is unassigned by running - 

GET _cluster/allocation/explain
{
  "index": "<index-name>",
  "shard": <shard-id>,
  "primary": true
}

Comment: Thanks! The `restore_in_progress` decider is reporting `[ULTRAWARM INTERNAL EXCEPTION]` on all three nodes. UltraWarm data nodes are not (and have never been) enabled for the cluster, and cannot be anyway because I don't have a dedicated master. The `unassigned_info` block has reason `MANUAL_ALLOCATION` with the same `ultrawarm` message in details. I will try again on a new cluster today as that looks like something AWS internal has gone wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately newly created clusters still fail.

Comment: Was that index stored on ultrawarm node when snapshot was taken..if not, better option is to reach out to AWS support for explanation

Comment: It wasn't, it had the same node set-up too (3 data, no dedicated master, 1AZ). Thanks for the help, will raise a support tikcet.